# How to bind angular property to model as array?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

My component is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class LocationModel {
  name: string;
  position: { 
    center: any[]
  }
} 

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  model: LocationModel = new LocationModel();

  onSubmit() {    
    console.log(this.model);
  }
}
```

And HTML component template is:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
 Location name: 
 <input 
   type="text"
   [(ngModel)]="model.name"
   name="firstName"><br>
lon: 
 <input 
   type="text" 
   [(ngModel)]="model.positon.center[1]"
   name="lon"><br>
lat:
 <input 
   type="text" 
   [(ngModel)]="model.positon.center[0]"
   name="lat"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{{model|json}}
```

But I could not create a json template like following:

```
{ "name": "some name", "position": { "center": [ 30.6067, 490.5563189 ] } }
```

Comment: it looks like both lat and long are bound to the same thing: `model.position.center[0]`. I think what you want to do is have one of them be bound to `model.position.center[1]`

Comment: typo in template: positon

Comment: any error you are getting in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try like this,

**Assigning `initial value` to `center`**

```
export class LocationModel {
  name: string;
  position: { 
    center: ["",""]
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
 Location name: 
 <input 
   type="text"
   [(ngModel)]="model.name"
   name="firstName"><br>
lon: 
 <input 
   type="text" 
   [(ngModel)]="model.positon.center[1]"
   name="lon"><br>
lat:
 <input 
   type="text" 
   [(ngModel)]="model.positon.center[0]"
   name="lat"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{{model|json}}
```

Comment: Center items should be number but set as text. How can I cast?

Comment: You can take any value for center before assiging new values, you can take,  `center: [0,0]`

Comment: But json is composed like `{ "center": [ "1", "2"] }` but it should be `{ "center": [ 1, 2] }`

Comment: then take a number field instead of text field as input